# JQuery UI resizable if <div> resized -> all siblings move too

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Hi I use the [jQuery UI Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/) and [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) for all of my three div elements.

The basic Dom tree looks like this:

[image]

So basically `blue` and `red` are siblings and orange is the  parent.

If I resize `blue` vertically then `red` automatically changes its position that the vertical space between them  stays the same. This problem does not apply to `Draggable`, so I can change the vertical distance by dragging `blue` and `red` around but every time I resize blue vertically red moves too.

If I make blue bigger vertically -> red moves down, I do not want that optimatically it would be that you can make blue bigger vertically until it hits the border of red and then thats it.
[image]

I tried several .css styles but nothing works

Here is the current .css that I use:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a working example in codepen or something?  From my understanding you are saying resizing blue works as expected, but when you drag blue and then resize it, red moves...somewhere?

Comment: ok I try to give a JSFiddle

Comment: If I make blue bigger vertically -> red moves down, I do not want that optimatically it would be that you can make blue bigger vertically until it hits the border of red and then thats it.

Comment: @ViktorCarlson it sounds like you're looking for collision detection between the various elements. Such that you cannot resize something to overlap with another element on the page. Would this be correct?

Comment: Yes exactely, ther is already the possibility to set the parameter `containment: "parent` that works tha blue and red cannot be resized / dragged outside of their parent and I would need a parameter like `containment: "siblings"`

Comment: oh i understand, you want the resizing to not overlap with siblings, or push them away, but to stop on their bounds.

Comment: Yes, the ´push them away´ is not not even when you start touching its that it keep alwas the same distance if i resize which means red moves down if I start to resize blue, before blue hits the border of red

Comment: @ViktorCarlson this will end up being something done in the `resize` function that  will return false when there is edge detection. Waiting for your fiddle before offering an answer.

Comment: @ViktorCarlson twisty is right, the only way to hook on it would be the resize function.  You could always set the element with absolute position which should get rid of the "push them away from each other" functionality.  

So what do you want for draggable? Draggable should cause them to overlap? I thought you didnt want any overlap?

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks for all your comments, I could find the solution:

`JQuery UI resizable` adds the .css attribute `position:relative;` to every resizable `<div>` element. 
I explain it to myself like this:

["relative:     The element is positioned relative to its normal position, so 'bottom:20px' adds 20 pixels to the element's BOTTOM position"](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

This means the normal position of red is directely under blue, but because of `draggable` we added, lets say 20px of space by dragging red down.

If you resize blue, then this 20px of space will be preserved, by moving red down.

When we use `position`: absolute !important; then red is always positioned 
"[relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)"
which is orange

```
/*overrides the '.ui-resizable' 'position:relative;' this helps that after resizing the position of the element
get placed relative to its parent <div>*/
position: absolute !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should give you some ideas.  It works for resizing the blue box and when it hits the top of the red box it stops.  So first see that you can not resize the blue since it starts flush to the red.  Then MOVE red down a little diagonally to the bottom right.  Now, if you resize the blue, it will hit the constraint of the red box.

I showed only one side of the constraint (from blue to red) to see if this helps before applying it to (red to blue).  Actually, there would be at least 4 constraints: top, bottom, left, right.

Pay attention to the two css position attributes I added.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>OOIndex</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        /*div {
            outline: 1px solid black;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            min-height: 30px;
            min-width: 500px;
        }*/

        .resizable {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
        }

        .orange {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: orange;
            /*added*/
            position: absolute;
        }

        .blue {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
        }

        .red {
            background-color: red;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 0.5em;
            /*added*/
            position: fixed;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            var targetRed = $('.red').position();
            $("#redPos").text("left " + targetRed.left + " top" + targetRed.top)
            var targetBlue = $('.blue').position();
            $("#bluePos").text("left " + targetBlue.left + " top" + targetBlue.top)

            $('#blueResiz').resizable({
                resize: function (event, ui) {
                    targetPos = $('.red').position();
                    $("#redPos").text("left " + targetPos.left + " top" + targetPos.top)
                    var added = ui.position.top + ui.size.height;
                    $("#bluePos").text("top " + ui.position.top + " height" + ui.size.height + " total " + added)

                    //if blue
                    if (ui.position.top + ui.size.height < targetPos.top) {
                        $(this).resizable({ maxHeight: targetPos.top - 20 });
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#redDrag').draggable({
                drag: function (event, ui) {

                    targetPos = $('.red').position();

                }
            })
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body class="orange">
    <div class="blue draggable" id="blueResiz">
        <div id="bluePos"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="red draggable" id="redDrag">
        <div id="redPos"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```